# Condition in do block

Tags: haskell, io

Why does the following block of code:

```
main = do
    line <- getLine
    if null line
        then runTestTT tests
        else do
            line2 <- getLine
            seq::[Int] <- return $ map read $ words line2
            print $ process seq
```

throw an error:

```
lgis.hs:28:13:
    Couldn't match type `()' with `Counts'
    Expected type: IO Counts
      Actual type: IO ()
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ process seq
    In the expression:
      do { line2 <- getLine;
           seq :: [Int] <- return $ map read $ words line2;
           print $ process seq }
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      if null line then
          runTestTT tests
      else
          do { line2 <- getLine;
               seq :: [Int] <- return $ map read $ words line2;
               print $ process seq }
```

Even though both:

```
main = do
    runTestTT tests
```

and

```
main = do
    line <- getLine
    line2 <- getLine
    seq::[Int] <- return $ map read $ words line2
    print $ process seq
```

work fine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both branches of an `if then else` must have the same type, but

```
runTestTT tests :: IO Counts
```

and

```
print $ process seq :: IO ()
```

You can add a `return ()` to the `then` branch, the modern way to do that is to use [`Control.Monad.void`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v%3avoid),

```
main = do
    line <- getLine
    if null line
        then void (runTestTT tests)         -- formerly: runTestTT tests >> return ()
        else do
            line2 <- getLine
            seq::[Int] <- return $ map read $ words line2
            print $ process seq
```

to fix it (or you could add a `return some_value_of_type_Counts` to the `else` branch).

Comment: This is what `void` is for: `then void (runTestTT tests)`

Comment: True. Thanks for the heads-up, I haven't yet got used to all the new convenience functions.

Comment: Is there some way to make a `>>`-like operator sufficiently polymorphic to deal with this? `a>>b` doesn't care what type `a` produces; I would think of it naturally as taking some sort of existentially quantified type, but I don't know if Haskell (or Glasgow Haskell) has the right sort.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm sorry, I don't understand. In `if condition then this else that`, the types of `this` and `that` must unify. You could of course make something like `iffy :: (Monad m) => Bool -> m a -> m b -> m ()` if that's what you mean.

Comment: @DanielFischer, that's a perfectly good work-around, but what I was getting at is that it's probably possible (but probably not in Haskell) to unify those types in some sense. `m a` and `m b` are each of type `exists c . m c` or some such.